# Error while searching for service jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider

Tags: jax-ws, jakarta-migration

I have a code which is using `jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider` to hit a url.
As a response I am getting `jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error while searching for service [jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider]`.

This was working fine in Java EE 8. After migrating to Jakarta EE 10 I started facing this issue.
Also I have added the below dependencies.

```
     <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: I had this issue as well. Turns out one of my dependencies caused the issue. One of my dependences used javax.xml.ws which is not compatible with java 17. I had to remove the dependency completely and find an alternative.

Comment: @devSouth555 which was that dependency you used?

Comment: @devSouth555 What was the alternative